# jquery prevent submit and submit again on popup button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to ,

1. Prevent the form Submit
2. Open a pop up
3. Submit the form again on click of Ok button of the above pop up.

I tried this ,

```
            $('#continueForm').one('submit', function(e) {
                var curr=$('input#hdncurrency').val();

                var inrDiv = $("<div />");
                if (curr=='INR') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    inrDiv.ajaxDialog({
                        url: '@Url.Action("PopUpOnINRflow", "optionalextras")',
                        closeOnEscape: false,
                        success: function (content) {
                            $(content).find("#inrcontinue").click(function (e) {
                                inrDiv.ajaxDialog('close');
                                showLoader(); //TILL THIS IS WORKING
                                $('#continueForm').submit(); //THIS IS NOT HAPPENING AND NO CONSOLE ERRORS
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    $("input[type='submit']", this).val("Please Wait...").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    document.getElementById("cancelAmndment").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    return true;
                }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the form? I think to have to add `type=' submit'` on the button.

Comment: Use `$('#continueForm')[0].submit();` to submit the form in your `success:`

Answer (score 0):

you should replace

```
$('#continueForm').one
```

by

```
$('#continueForm').on
```

Comment: that will take you in loops of form Submit .

Comment: have you tried to move e.preventDefault(); outside the if else block ?